# How can I insert text in an html element stored in a variable?

Tags: php

I have a program which is copying the text from another website and showing it.

It is storing the text in a variable `$string`.
The variable is containing html tags in it and I want to add text before a html tag stored in the variable.

For example: `$string="<div id='1'><div id='game'></div>";` I want to add text before the `div` whose id is `game`.

Comment: What is the exact output string you're trying to create?

Comment: Your tags are confusing. Are you doing this on the server in PHP, or on the client in Javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

To add the text before the div whose id is 'game'. simply use:

```
$string = "<div id='1'><div id='game'></div>";
$new = "texttoinsert";
$pos = "<div id='game'></div>";
echo str_replace($pos, $new.$pos ,$string);
```

Answer (score 2):

In php the easiest way to do this would be using str_replace (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$textToInsert = "test";
$string = str_replace("<div id='game'>", $textToInsert."<div id='game'>" ,$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

For that particular case the following works:

```
$($string).prepend("text");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/apV25/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery the solution is simple:

```
var text = $("<div id='1'><div id='game'></div></div>");

$('#1', text).prepend('text-to-insert');
```

and the result HTML can be obtained like this: `text.html()` 
I hope this help.